# Windows 10 group policy letter drive map vs manually mapped drive letter

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, mapped-drive

Our network is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2.  PCs with Windows 10 are hosted on this domain with
a [user group policy](https://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/05/how-to-apply-a-group-policy-object-to-individual-users-or-computer/) that maps a letter drive (J:) to a mount point that is defined as a [DFS with replication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-replication/dfsr-overview) which includes two replication groups, each having a set of replication folders.

On some of the PCs hosted on this same network there is a need to use the same letter drive, but mapped to another location.

My question is this:
Is it reasonable to expect that a [manually mapped, persistent letter drive](https://www.howtogeek.com/118452/how-to-map-network-drives-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows/) will reliably and consistently persist through a re-application of group policy for that login?  That is after a log-off/log-on sequence, or even a complete power-off/power-on, and log on.

Worded another way, will group policy overwrite manually mapped persistent drives, or let them persist even after multiple group policy forced updates?

Comment: People should be informed of what the Group Policy drives are and not use these drives manually. Yes group policy settings will override.

Comment: @John - The people that use the drives know what they are.  But we are seeing inconsistencies in how they behave.  If we are observing that the persistently mapped drive is remaining after reapplication of group policy, does that mean something is wrong with the DFS and/or replication process?  By the way, I did run a [diagnostic test and report](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/cc754227(v=ws.10)) from the Admin Tools.  It indication replication was okay.

Comment: They should be on your domain so drives map as part of the domain User settings. That is how we do this. Then only use other drive letters for misc. mappings. If no domain, then people just need to be consistent in how they map drives.